# ZeroMQ - sending more than 30 bytes with REQ socket

Tags: c++, sockets, zeromq

I'm having hard time understanding how to work with 0MZ properly. When I'm trying to send a message initialized with size larger than 29, something goes wrong. My code is very simple:

```
zmq::context_t context (1);
zmq::socket_t req(context,ZMQ_REQ);
req.connect("tcp://localhost:6969");

int msgSize = 100;
zmq::message_t test(msgSize);
snprintf((char*)test.data(),msgSize,"short message");
cout << static_cast<char*>(test.data())<< endl; // this is always fine - 'short message'
```

so far so good, but after sending this message, if `msgSize`>29, i can't get the same result again

```
req.send(test);
cout << static_cast<char*>(test.data())<< endl; // now it's gibberish, like '&?+#'
```

what's even more puzzling, if my server receives the message it also looks like '&?+#' there, but if it is sending it back simply with PUB socket, I can read it again in my client:

```
zmq::message_t reply;
req.recv(&reply);
cout << static_cast<char*>(test.data())<< endl; - 'my message' again!
```

I understand, that there is some 29 bytes limit on short messages, but how can i get around it, without dealing with multipart messages? I literally need like 40 chars....

Comment: According to the 0MQ documentation for [zmq_send()](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq-send), successful invocation of that function (`zmq::socket_t::send` wraps it) destroys the message. So you are not supposed to access the data member **after** the message has been queued. That it works for smaller messages is probably an implementation artefact.

Comment: But why is my message messed up on the server as well?

Comment: Note that in the last 3 lines of code shown, the received message is called `reply` but you still print the data content of `test`.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but on the server side is another part of code, not unlike the fragment above, only with `ZMQ_REP` socket handling test message sent from here (code above). Actually there's a poll going on on the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the message is > 30 bytes, the memory once occupied by 'test', but then freed, must be being reused by the reply data (obviously by serendipity). Thus, when you look at 'test' again it magically appears to be what you think it should be. This theory should be very simple for you to verify in the debugger by looking at addresses.

Whatever, as Hristo said, sending a message frees it's original contents and shouldn't be used again.

ZeroMQ has an optimisation for small messages where the payload doesn't need to be separately allocated. Again, the fact that you can still see the contents you expect after sending a message is just an artefact; you cannot rely on it.

If you have a requirement to retain the contents of messages after they're sent, take a look at zmq_send_const(), which is new with ZMQ 4.0. I don't know if any bindings make use of it.

Comment: I'm not sure, but that doesn,t explain why is the message also wrong on the server side?

Comment: @ClockworkOrkwork Difficult to say, you haven't posted your server code.

Comment: You're right, for now I can say there is a zmq::poll waiting for messages, I'lll add the code a litle later

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, I had an error generating piece of code within my server app, after receiving a message I did instant ping pong style reply, like:

```
zmq::message_t msg(msgSize);
REC.recv(&msg);
//pong
REC.send(msg);
```

And as above answer points out, sending a message frees it's original contents, leaving me with unwanted gibberish of random bytes.